# Using VBA to open files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to open the file automatically after clicking the button, the folder is the same and the file name is the same every month. I wanted it to always select the most recent file from teog msc, e.g. if not, it would say that the file is too old. However, And i get error now Object Variable or With Block not Set . Here
`data_wb.Sheets("Adekwatnosc").Rows("1:1").Select`
This code like a would like create .To open my file automatically

```
   ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
   MyFolder = "C:\Users\V1410191\Documents\Final" & ThisMonth & ""
   MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\FinalPrice*.xlsm")
   Do Until MyFile = ""
   MyFile = Dir
Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

Loop
```

And  here is the code I have.

````
Dim vDate As Date
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim data_wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim inputbx As String
Dim loc As Range, lc As Long
Dim MyFolder As String, ThisMonth As String
Dim MyFile As String

'Set workbook'

Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook
With wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Rows("1:1")
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
  End With
  
Application.ThisWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever '2
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
file_name = selectFilePK
If file_name = "" Then Exit Sub
Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(file_name)


   'paste copy like value and change to date format'
   data_wb.Sheets("Adekwatnosc").Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
 
 Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD", , Format(VBA.Now, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        vDate = DateValue(inputbx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(vDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid
       

     

     data_wb.Worksheets("Adekwatnosc").Activate
     With data_wb.Worksheets("Adekwatnosc")
        Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            lc = .Cells(loc.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(109, loc.Column), .Cells(123, lc)).Copy
      Set locPaste = wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells(27, locPaste.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    End With
data_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
MsgBox "Wklejone!"
End Sub
Private Function selectFilePK()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsm"

        If .Show = True Then selectFilePK = .SelectedItems(1)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        End With
End Function```
````

Comment: `MyFolder` ends with \ but you also included \ in the concatenation inside `Dir` so the filepath would have `...\\FinalPrice...`

Comment: Also, should there be a \ after `PriceQ`?

Answer (score 0):

in your initial code:

```
ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
MyFolder = "C:\Users\G2121290\Documents\PriceQ" & ThisMonth & "\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\FinalPrice*.xlsx")
Do Until MyFile = ""
    Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(file_name, UpdateLinks:=0)
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
```

in the `Open` statement you are using `file_name` instead of `MyFile` which you previously defined

Comment: I changed still same problems like before :( `ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
   MyFolder = "C:\Users\G2121290\Documents\PriceQ" & ThisMonth & "\"
   MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "FinalPrice*.xlsm")
   Do Until MyFile = ""
       Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
MyFile = Dir`

Comment: please update the OP with the current code so that we can see what variables are being used and where/how are they declared, and stuff

Comment: what is `file_name = selectFilePK`?

Comment: I think its releated with function open dialog . SelectFilePK jest function

Comment: Now, i get error Run Time Error '91' : `Object Variable or With Block not Set` here  data_wb.Sheets("Pricing").Rows("1:1").Select

Comment: the info you show are too fragmentary
I guess you have to update the OP code by carefully pick up all the code you really need to show and have people uderstand the scenario without wasting time in reading unnecessary code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237628/discussion-between-whyexcelme-and-user3598756).

Answer (score -1):

Add a line that helps your debugging, like this:

```
file_name = selectFilePK
Debug.Print file_name
If file_name = "" Then Exit Sub
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to show the debug output before running. The value there is the file that is expected to be opened. If that is wrong in some way, adjust `selectFilePK` accordingly.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. From the SO guide about answering: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative." Telling someone to use the debugging tools is nice advice but not solving their immediate question.