# VBA Object Variable or With Block not Set when i trying open file

Tags: excel, vba

Why i get error here when selecting a file directly from a folder without a dialog box. What am I doing wrong and where can the error be

```
  ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm")
   MyFolder = "C:\Users\V1410191\Documents\Final" & ThisMonth & ""
   MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\FinalPrice*.xlsm")
   Do Until MyFile = ""
   MyFile = Dir
Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
  data_wb.Sheets("Adekwatnosc").Rows("1:1").Select   <--here shows debugs
```

If i run by browser(dialogbox) select file and i dont have a bug :

```
MyFile = selectFilePK
If MyFile = "" Then Exit Sub
Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)


  'paste copy like value and change to date format'
  data_wb.Sheets("Adekwatnosc").Rows("1:1").Select


Private Function selectFilePK()
   Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd
       .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Filters.Clear
       .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsm"

       If .Show = True Then selectFilePK = .SelectedItems(1)
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
       End With
End Function
```

Comment: The `Dir` function only returns a filename, not a filename with a path. You have to add the path to the `.Open` filename.

Comment: Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\V1410191\Documents\Final", MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)   ? or i not ? im not sure i good understood

Comment: why are you duplicating an already published thread of yours?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363936/using-vba-to-open-files-in-a-folder/69367838?noredirect=1#comment122615694_69367838

Comment: im not duplicating, I changed the question only . If you want, I can delete them

Comment: `Set data_wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)`

Comment: Thanks, but not help ;(

Comment: Its resolved thank for you guys !